# How to get length of YTickLabels in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a MATLAB subplot figure. I need the YLabels to left align justify. To do this I am setting the Position property for each ylabel. My problem is the subplots are being created programmatically and therefore I don't know what to set the position as.

In MATLAB I want to use the longest/widest YTickLabel as a reference point for positioning. To do that I want to get the length of each label. I am able to get the YTickLabels by doing:

```
% Set Label format as string
set(gca, 'YTickLabel', num2str(transpose(get(gca, 'YTick'))))
% Get axis YTickLabels
ax = gca;
labels = get(ax, 'YTickLabel');
% Print labels to console
disp(labels)
```

I would like to iterate through the labels and find the length of the longest label. I've tried accessing them as a cell array but get 'Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object error.' And when I try matrix indexing nothing prints.

Does anyone know if it is possible to get the length of each individual YTickLabel value?

Useful info:

MATLAB R2014b

Answer (score 2):

By "length of each individual YTickLabel value" I understand that you wish to get the number of characters forming each label.

It's quite easy using the `numel` function, which outputs the number of elements in a cell for an example. Since `labels` are stored in a cell array, we can use the fancy function `cellfun` to apply `numel` to each cell, then convert to a numeric array with `cell2mat`

In short you can use this:

```
LabelLength = cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) numel(x),labels,'uni',0))
```

here is some sample code to illustrate:

```
clear
clc
close all

x = 1:5;

y = rand(size(x));

scatter(x,y,40,'r','filled')

set(gca,'YTick',[1 3 5],'YTickLabel',{'One';'ThisIsThree';'AndFive'})
grid on

labels = get(gca,'YTickLabel')

LabelLength = cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) numel(x),labels,'uni',0))
```

and output:

```
LabelLength =

     3
    11
     7
```

You could replace `cellfun` with this equivalent for-loop:

```
LabelLength = zeros(numel(labels),1);
for k = 1:numel(labels)

    LabelLength(k) = numel(labels{k});

end
LabelLength
```

Note that as a workaround offering quite a lot of flexibility, you could replace the `YTickLabels` by [text](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) objects, for which you can set the `HorizontalAlignment` property to `left` for the text to be left-justified.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I tried the solution with my code and got the following error:                                       Error using cellfun
Input #2 expected to be a cell array, was char instead.

Error in subplottest (line 58)
LabelLength = cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) numel(x),labels,'uni',0));

Comment: what is the exact code you used to generate that error? Plus what if you use the loop? Its likely that `labels` is somehow not a cell array